# can't change popup location firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, popup

normally on firefox, Ctrl-T opens a new tab, and Ctrl-L focuses on the URL entry bar, where I can edit and go to a new location.

```
window.open('myurl.php','infowindow','width=750,height=750');
```

since about several years ago, these are no longer possible for "pop-up" windows that don't have the toolbar etc..  Ctrl-T does nothing, and the URL is no longer editable manually.  Why did Firefox do this?  They must know I can use Javascript to do this, why make these restrictions on Javascript-opened popups?

are there any add-ons that DO allow you to open another tab in a pop-up?  Or, can I change this in :about settings.  Thanks.

Comment: Opening another tab in a popup? Like, opening a new window?

Comment: yes, a popup with the url showing, but nothing else.  these are utility windows or "add-a-record" windows in my applications.  But Ctrl-T does not work on these type of popups and I'd like to change settings to allow them to work.

Comment: popup windows may just be disabled in the browser. check!

Comment: Is it mandatory to use popups? Won't a inline pop-up like Fancybox(http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples) or Bootstrap's modal(http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) suffice ?

Comment: although I will look at the fancyapps thing, NO I want to have a separate popup due to complete dom independence, and the fact that you can move the entire pop-up completely and visibly away from the work area.  And again, I'd like to have multiple tabs in a popup that is opened with no toolbar but a URL bar